# Transformation of general equation of second degree with respect to a rectangular axes

Tags: geometry, transformation, rotations

**Question :**
The equation $3x^2+2xy+3y^2-18x-22y+50=0$ is transformed to $4x^2+2y^2=1$ with respect to a rectangular axes through the point $(2,3)$ inclined to the original axes at an angle $\theta$. Then $\theta$ is

(a) $\pi/3$
(b)  $\pi/8$
(c) $\pi/4$
(d)  $3\pi/2$
  Progress :
Put  $x=x+2$ and $y=y+3$ in the given equation, we get
$3(x+2)^2+2(x+2)(y+3)+3(y+3)^2-18(x+2)-22(y+3)+50=0$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Rotation_of_conic_sections

Answer (score 1):

By using a suitable translation---in fact, the given one, though we don't need to know that here---we can find new coordinates, also (mildly abusively) denoted $(x, y)$, for which the linear terms on the l.h.s. of the equation vanish. NB this translation affects neither the quadratic terms nor the angle of rotation, so we may as well ask about the rotation of the ellipse in these coordinates, which thus has equation
$$\phantom{(\ast)} \qquad 3 x^2 + 2 x y + 3 y^2 = C \qquad (\ast)$$
for some suitable constant $C$ (one can check that for the $C$ that occurs here, this equation really does define an ellipse, that is, it is neither empty nor a single point).

**Hint** The equation $(\ast)$ is symmetric in the variables $x, y$, and hence the ellipse it defines is fixed under the reflection $(x, y) \mapsto (y, x)$.

> **Additional hint** The ellipse is thus symmetric about the line of reflection $y = x$; what angle does this make with, say, the $x$-axis?